# Magento 2 Confirmation widget confirm action

Tags: magento2, widget, confirmation

I'm trying to execute a function on confirm widget confirmation, but the confirm action is firing on load page always.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="action accept" id="accept_user" href="#">
    <span>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Accept'); ?>
    </span>
</a>
```

And Here the JS:

```
<script>
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ],
    function($, confirmation) {
        $('#accept_user').on('click', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            confirmation({
                title: 'Accept user',
                content: 'Do you want to accept this user?',
                actions: {

                    confirm: function () {
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->activateUser('$userId'); ?>
                    },

                    cancel: function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to execute the confirm action only when user click on Accept button from confirmation modal?

It's for frontend area.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have called `echo $block->activateUser('$userId');` inside it. The correct way should be if you call ajax to a controller and put your logic for `activateUser` in it. Something like this:

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
],
function($, confirmation) {
    $('#accept_user').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        confirmation({
            title: 'Accept user',
            content: 'Do you want to accept this user?',
            actions: {

                confirm: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                         showLoader: true,
                         url: 'route-for-controller',
                         data: {},
                         type: "POST",
                         success: function (data) {
                             console.log(data);
                             <!-- things you want to perform on success or you can reload the page to show changes -->
                         },
                         error: function (error) {
                             
                         }
                    });
                },

                cancel: function () {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```